# How to reload a class or package in Scala REPL?

Tags: scala, read-eval-print-loop

I almost always have a Scala REPL session or two open, which makes it very easy to give Java or Scala classes a quick test.  But if I change a class and recompile it, the REPL continues with the old one loaded.  Is there a way to get it to reload the class, rather than having to restart the REPL?

Just to give a concrete example, suppose we have the file Test.scala:

```
object Test { def hello = "Hello World" }
```

We compile it and start the REPL:

```
~/pkg/scala-2.8.0.Beta1-prerelease$ bin/scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.8.0.Beta1-prerelease
(Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM, Java 1.6.0_16).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> Test.hello
res0: java.lang.String = Hello World
```

Then we change the source file to

```
object Test {
  def hello = "Hello World"
  def goodbye = "Goodbye, Cruel World"
}
```

but we can't use it:

```
scala> Test.goodbye
<console>:5: error: value goodbye is not a member of object Test
       Test.goodbye
            ^

scala> import Test;
<console>:1: error: '.' expected but ';' found.
       import Test;
```

Comment: I guess that's one benefit of worksheets over the REPL

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Class reloading is not an easy problem.  In fact, it's something that the JVM makes very difficult.  You do have a couple options though:

- Start the Scala REPL in debug mode.  The JVM debugger has some built-in reloading which works on the method level.  It won't help you with the case you gave, but it would handle something simple like changing a method implementation.
- Use JRebel (http://www.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel).  JRebel is basically a super-charged class reloading solution for the
  JVM.  It can handle
  member addition/removal, new/removed classes, definition changes, etc.  Just about the only thing it *can't* handle is changes in class hierarchy (adding a super-interface, for
  example).  It's not a free tool, but they do offer a complementary license which is limited to Scala compilation units.

Unfortunately, both of these are limited by the Scala REPL's implementation details.  I use JRebel, and it usually does the trick, but there are still cases where the REPL will not reflect the reloaded class(es).  Still, it's better than nothing.

Comment: How do you start the scala repl in debug mode?  I'm using sbt and running 'console' to start the scala repl for my project, but not sure how this could be done in debug mode.

Answer (score 41):

There is an alternative to reloading the class if the goal is to not have to repeat previous commands.  The REPL has the command

```
:replay
```

which restarts the REPL environment and plays back all previous valid commands.  (The invalid ones are skipped, so if it was wrong before, it won't suddenly work.)  When the REPL is reset, it does reload classes, so new commands can use the contents of recompiled classes (in fact, the old commands will also use those recompiled classes).

This is not a general solution, but is a useful shortcut to extend an individual session with re-computable state.

<sup>Note: this applies to the bare Scala REPL.  If you run it from SBT or some other environment, it may or may not work depending on how SBT or the other environment packages up classes--if you don't update what is on the actual classpath being used, of course it won't work!</sup>

Comment: Obviously bad for intensive sessions, but I like this. It also means you'll know if your changes broke anything, if testing/TDD is your aim.

Comment: I believe this is wrong.  `:replay` does *not* reload classes.

Comment: I agree with @AdamMackler, at least it doesn't seem to reload with 2.10.4.

Comment: @mitchus - I just verified the reloading behavior for 2.11.6.  It doesn't work for me inside SBT, though, at least not in any straightforward way.  I haven't checked 2.10.4 specifically.

Comment: @RexKerr true, my observations are also w.r.t. the "sbt console"

Comment: It works! With a bit of tinker. Have two Console windows open. On one you compile scala files with "scalac *.scala". On the other window you just use the :replay after the compile is done and your good to go! EDIT: it worked now when I add new functions it's not working! Gosh

Answer (score 9):

There is an command meet you requirement

```
:load path/to/file.scala
```

which will reload the scala source file and recompiled to classes , then you can replay you code

Comment: Does this work for you if `file.scala` has a `package` defined at the top?  Thanks

Answer (score 7):

This works for me....

If your new source file `Test.scala` looks something like this...

```
package com.tests

object Test {
  def hello = "Hello World"
  def goodbye = "Goodbye, Cruel World"
}
```

You first have to load the new changes into Scala console (REPL).

```
:load src/main/scala/com/tests/examples/Test.scala
```

Then re-import the package so you can reference the new code in Scala console.

```
import com.tests.Test
```

Now enjoy your new code without restarting your session :)

```
scala> Test.goodbye
res0: String = Goodbye, Cruel World
```

Comment: This works for me only if no `package` is defined at the top of `Test.scala`.  Any ideas?  Thanks

Comment: Do not know. Perhaps bad package path

Answer (score 2):

If the .scala file is in the directory where you start the REPL you can ommit the full path, just put `:load myfile.scala`, and then import.