# REPL for Delphi IDE?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, read-eval-print-loop

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/REPL Read–eval–print_loop

Is there such a thing for Delphi ?
It would be rather useful to explore DLLs such as Windows APi and sketch their usage, when dealing with border cases scarcely documented.

I tried pascal scripts, such as one in Cnwizards, but it is much less comfortable.
For example it cannot use units like Windows.pas and you had to make some strange stubs of your own for it.

And anyway, those scripts are less easy to use for "try this try that" scenario than Repl.

For Delphi objects most clsoe thing it to pause on breakpoint and use Evaluate/Modify window, but it only works with Delphi objects, not DLLs; it cannot make temporary vars to cache values and such.

Comment: No point forcing a square peg into a round hole. Use Python (or similar) if you want some REPL.

Comment: Java/Scala do have REPLs and they are compilable languages too.

Using Python to construct and test Delphi code over Windows API DLLs is forcing pages per se, no less than adding interpreater-like features into compiling language IDE.

Comment: I think would be hilarious to have to type in "public static void main()" and then some curly brackets and imports just to interactively `printf("hello world")`. Java REPL. Hilarious!

Comment: sure. So i guess there are default imports, like autoexec.bat :-)
and there surely are no need to key in "public static void main()" (there could be sense if you go for function-reference variable, but Java lacks those). The boilerplate needed for regular projects may and must be reduced. Like in: http://www.scala-lang.org/node/2009 http://scala-ide.org/docs/user/features/scalainterpreter.html http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471947/

Answer (score 3):

It's not really what you're looking for, because Delphi is a statically typed, compiled language, but if you really insist on being able to type some pascal in and see if it does anything, you can try the `TJvInterpreter` component that comes in the Jedi VCL.

Note that the experience is nothing like using python. You can't just type "uses module" and hit enter, because pascal units must be complete before they can even be interpreted by JvInterpreter, and the JvInterpreter needs you to write a wrapper for every single other unit you want to import. You would go crazy.  I'm not seriously advising anybody to try to build a REPL around `TJvInterpreter`.

The "interactive magic" element of Delphi is called the "designtime environment" and the way we build using "components". We don't even do that bit by writing code much, we do it all visually with our mouse and keyboard. It's called RAD (rapid application development) and is powered by the VCL (visual component library) in Delphi, and (like REPL) is one of the many ways of doing very-rapid development.

The other thing we have that is a lot like a REPL is this button in Delphi:

[image]

You click it, after creating a new empty project, and whatever code you added to your new empty project is built and running in less than a second. Close enough to a REPL for me. It's kind of like binary executable instant bliss.

Write one line. Build and run (1 second). Instant.

Comment: Yup, delphi is a different rapid development scheme, wherein the programmer is expected to think about the program they build, and use the compiler and very thorough help docs for hammering out issues.

Comment: +1, especially about not needing an interpreter because the compiler's speed (and `Code Insight`, which you didn't mention) make it unnecessary. Nice answer, Warren. :-)

Comment: Code Insight ? you pulling my leg! IDE-embedded J#-based pascal parser is incomplete and out of sync with main compiler. It cannot find library files, when they are in both projects's and IDE's search and browse paths. It fails to parse language constructs and declare all the rest of units as an error. There were reports about instantly crashing IDE when heavily using generics. So, yes, there are Code Insight with limited reliability. But it is not always working even for perfectly described functions, left alone those scarcely descibed that need trial and error session

Comment: "and the JvInterpreter needs you to write a wrapper for every single other unit you want to import." Yes, exactly like the script in CnWizards. Like if they are forked from same root. That is a ridiculous need for tedious manual work. As u said "You would go crazy." I went. Then i went to SO :-)

Comment: "Close enough to a REPL for me." 
And then use breakpoint + Inspect/Evaluate to check the results. And if you need to change few parameter values - then you'd better re-run.
If you need to change few lines and rewire logic - then you should re-compile and re-run.

Well, seems we have no other option yet. But it is not REPL.
Frankly, i tend to have the same snobbish thought. 
REPL ? is for Basic kids. We have The Real Language. The one that compiles, have types, etc. But then i checked REPL in Scala. If technically possible, then for some purposes it IS useful in staticalyl-typed lanhuages too.

Comment: C++ is a statically typed compiled language, and they get an interpreter https://root.cern/cling/

Comment: And it basically does what I'm saying, which is compile and run, it just does so quickly. Which is what Delphi already does.  cling is not an interpreter.  If you don't understand what interpreter means, please do a little more reading.  They say it's an interpreter. Yes. it accepts code and runs it.  It's a REPL (read execute print loop) but to be an interpreter would mean it's no longer a compiler.

"uses just-in-time (JIT) compiler for compilation."

SO, not an interpreter.  We can call a truck a popsicle, and we can lick it, but it doesn't make a truck a popsicle.