# What is the difference between Clojure REPL and Scala REPL?

Tags: scala, clojure

I’ve been working with Scala language for a few months and I’ve already created couple projects in Scala. I’ve found Scala REPL (at least its IntelliJ worksheet implementation) is quite convenient for quick development. I can write code, see what it does and it’s nice. But I do the procedure only for functions (not whole program). I can’t start my application and change it on spot. Or at least I don’t know how (so if you know you are welcome to give me piece of advice).

Several days ago my associate told me about Clojure REPL. He uses Emacs for development process and he can change code on spot and see results without restarting. For example, he starts the process and if he changes implementation of a function, his code will change his behavior without restart. I would like to have the same thing with Scala language.

P.S. I want to discuss neither which language is better nor does functional programming better than object-oriented one. I want to find a good solution. If Clojure is the better language for the task so let it be.

Comment: One is used to write Clojure, the other to write Scala. Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471947/is-there-an-easy-way-to-get-the-scala-repl-to-reload-a-class-or-package

Comment: It's a little hard for me to know what a correct answer would look like? Are you perhaps asking if the Scala REPL can redefine functions in a running program?

Comment: Curiosity, the question is good, but the title is not.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The short answer is that Clojure was designed to use a very simple, single pass compiler which reads and compiles a single s-expression or form at a time. For better or worse there is no global type information, no global type inference and no global analysis or optimization. Clojure uses `clojure.lang.Var` instances to create global bindings through a series of hashmaps from textual symbols to transactional values. `def` forms all create bindings at global scope in this global binding map. So where in Scala a "function" (method) will be resolved to an instance or static method on a given JVM class, in Clojure a "function" (def) is really just a reference to an entry in the table of var bindings. When a function is invoked, there isn't a static link to another class, instead the var is reference by symbolic name, then dereferenced to get an instance of a `clojure.lang.IFn` object which is then invoked.

This layer of indirection means that it is possible to re-evaluate only a single definition at a time, and that re-evaluation becomes globaly visible to all clients of the re-defined var.

In comparison, when a definition in Scala changes, scalac must reload the changed file, macroexpand, type infer, type check, and compile. Then due to the semantics of classloading on the JVM, scalac must also reload all classes which depend on methods in the class which changed. Also all values which are instances of the changed class become trash.

Both approaches have their strengths and weaknesses. Obviously Clojure's approach is simpler to implement, however it pays an ongoing cost in terms of performance due to continual function lookup operations forget correctness concerns due to lack of static types and what have you. This is arguably suitable for contexts in which lots of change is happening in a short timeframe (interactive development) but is less suitable for context when code is mostly static (deployment, hence Oxcart). [some work I did](https://www.arrdem.com/2014/08/06/of_oxen,_carts_and_ordering/) suggests that the slowdown on Clojure programs from lack of static method linking is on the order of 16-25%. This is not to call Clojure slow or Scala fast, they just have different priorities.

Scala chooses to do more work up front so that the compiled application will perform better which is arguably more suitable for application deployment when little or no reloading will take place, but proves a drag when you want to make lots of small changes.

Some material I have on hand about compiling Clojure code more or less cronological by publication order since Nicholas influenced my GSoC work a lot.

- [Clojure Compilation](http://blog.ndk.io/clojure-compilation.html) [Nicholas]
- [Clojure Compilation: Full Disclojure](http://blog.ndk.io/clojure-compilation2.html) [Nicholas]
- [Why is Clojure bootstrapping so slow?](http://blog.ndk.io/clojure-bootstrapping.html) [Nicholas]
- [Oxcart and Clojure](https://www.arrdem.com/2014/06/26/oxcart_and_clojure/) [me]
- [Of Oxen, Carts and Ordering](https://www.arrdem.com/2014/08/06/of_oxen,_carts_and_ordering/) [me]

Which I suppose leaves me in the unhappy place of saying simply "I'm sorry, Scala wasn't designed for that the way Clojure was" with regards to code hot swapping.

Comment: Gilad Bracha and other luminaries from the Smalltalk and Lisp worlds have this mantra that "Static Types are Coupling", and this is another example of that. It is – at least to the best of our current knowledge – simply not possible to implement a lively environment for a statically typed language, whereas dynamically typed languages have *extremely* powerful lively environments, check out the MIT Lisp Machine, Squeak/Pharo Smalltalk, Newspeak, Dan Ingall's Lively Kernel or the Self World.

Comment: Thank you all very much!

Comment: @JörgWMittag It's always a trade-off between being dynamic and being statically checkable. Sometimes you want one, sometimes you want the other. I tend to lean on the static typing side - mostly because I've seen quite a few bugs that occur even in Java because its type system is too lenient. That's not to dismiss the advantages of dynamic typing, for me the advantages of static typing simply weigh more. YMMV

Comment: thanks for this informative post. The links you provide on Clojure Compilation do not work - is it possible to update them please? Thanks